# Youtube video embed: how to remove youtube logo bottom right when controls=0 (modestbranding=1 does not work)

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I use my own videojs control bar at the bottom, which means I have to set the youtube embed link to `controls=0`, which means this logo always shows beneath my control bar. Setting `modestbranding=1` does not help the issue.

Is there a solution?

[image: As you can see the youtube logo shows underneath my control bar]

Comment: I don't think Youtube will let you hide their branding completely. If you want to hide the logo and are sure that it's not against TOS, you may opt to use gradient for the control's background so that the right side is opaque

Comment: @TomášZato this actually did the job perfectly: setting it to opaque. Thanks!